# Eliminating Abbreviations in UITextChecker

Tags: objective-c, ios, text

I am trying to create an app in which random words are generated, however I want abbreviations to be ignored when they are created. To do this i randomly generate an array of letters, (Weighting them with the same weighting as scrabble ;P) and then run through the array checking for correct words using UITextChecker like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        [word setString:@""];
        for (int j = i; j < 14 ;j++) {
            [word appendString:[letterArray objectAtIndex:j]];

            NSRange misspelledWord = [checkText rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:word range:NSMakeRange(0, word.length) startingAt:0 wrap:NO language:@"en_GB"];

            if (misspelledWord.location == NSNotFound && word.length > 2) {
                NSRange misspelledWordSecondRun = [checkText rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:word range:NSMakeRange(0, word.length) startingAt:0 wrap:NO language:@"en_US"];
                if (misspelledWordSecondRun.location == NSNotFound) {

                     NSLog(@"You generated the word: %@",word);
                }
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
```

The only problem is that this lets a ridiculous amount of abbreviations and acronyms through... is there any way I can reduce this number? There must be a language that I can send checkText which is an abbreviation free version of the english dictionary? Or some way of telling it to flag acronyms as misspelled words? As you can see I have tried to reduce the number by filtering the words a second time using us english rather than uk english, however this doesn't reduce the number of acronyms being let through at all :/

Comment: There is the class method `unlearnWord` for `UITextChecker`.  You could use that method to have it unlearn each acronym one by one.

Comment: not sure it's worth it for the hours of unlearning acronyms... There really are a lot of them! ;) Unless I could get a list of all of the acronyms contained in the UK dictionary apple uses. Any idea where I might find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented this using an array of words that I didn't want to include, each time a word is generated it checks to see if it's in this array. If it is it doesn't register it as a word, if it isn't it doesn't.

Comment: have you found a way to remove from uitextchecker?

Comment: As @dmur suggests you could call `unlearnWord:` on  `UITextChecker`. I personally wrote an array of words I didn't want to be included in the array of results and if the array contained a word returned by the spell checker I simply ignored it

Comment: In case anyone stumbles onto this answer many years later: keeping ignored words in an NSOrderedSet or NSMutableOrderedSet allows for much quicker lookup than an array. Kodeco.com (formerly RayWenderlich.com) has a good overview for Swift: https://www.kodeco.com/1172-collection-data-structures-in-swift